# Python/lxml web scraping: dealing with blank entries

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I'm using Python and lxml to scrape data on ETFs and mutual funds from the Bloomberg web site.  An example of a page I'm trying to scrape data from is http://www.bloomberg.com/markets/funds/country/usa/ .

For each fund, I need the symbol, name, fund type, and objective.  I'm having no problems scraping the symbol, name, or fund type.  However, I'm having difficulty with the objective.  You'll see on the web page I cited (and subsequent pages) that the objective is blank.  The HTML for this last fund on the page looks like:

```
    <tr class='tkr_alt'>
    <td class="name">
    <a href="/quote/ADTKEX:US"><span>Advisor Disciplined Trust 193 - Taxable Municipal Bond Portfolio - Series 1</span> (ADTKEX)</a></td>
    <td class="symbol">ADTKEX:US</td>
    <td>UIT</td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
```

The first column has the fund name, the second column has the ticker symbol, the third column has the fund type (ETF, UIT, open-end fund, closed-end fund, etc.), and the fourth column has the objective (growth, value, income, etc.).  For this particular fund, the objective is missing.

The code I'm using to extract the fund objective (the last column) is:

```
    result = urllib.urlopen(filename)
    element_html = result.read()
    doc = lxml.html.document_fromstring (element_html)
    list_obj = doc.xpath (u'.//tr[td[contains (@*, "name")]]/following-sibling::td/text()')
```

This code copies the fund objectives into an array.  Unfortunately, the code completely IGNORES the fact that an entry is missing.  Thus, the lists for the name, symbol, and fund type will each have X elements, but the list for the objective will only have X-1 elements.

How can I get the script to recognize the blank entry and provide an array element of nil or ''?

Is there a way I can capture the entire column entry (which would look something like "blahblahblah")?  I'm willing to deal with these unwanted tags, because they're easy to remove.

Comment: Not an answer, but you should definitely check out [Scrapy](https://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/0.16/intro/tutorial.html).

Answer (score 4):

Don't match the text node explicitly--just get the text value of the node:

```
doc.xpath(u'string(.//tr[td[contains (@*, "name")]]/following-sibling::td)')
```

Or you can do the same on the Python side:

```
tds = doc.xpath(u'.//tr[td[contains (@*, "name")]]/following-sibling::td')
etree.tostring(tds[0], method="text")
```

However I think your approach is wrong. Instead of getting four different lists and zipping them together, find the container rows and then get the items in that context all at once. Here is a complete implementation:

```
from lxml import etree
from collections import namedtuple

Fund = namedtuple('Fund', 'name symbol type objective')

def astext(elem):
    "Return stripped text value of element"
    return etree.tostring(elem, method='text').strip()

url = 'http://www.bloomberg.com/markets/funds/country/usa/'
xpfundrows = u"//table[@class='ticker_data']/descendant::tr[td[1][@class='name']]"


doc = etree.parse(url, etree.HTMLParser())

funds = []
for row in doc.xpath(xpfundrows):
    cells = row.findall('td')
    fund = Fund(astext(cell) for cell in cells)
    funds.append(fund)

print funds
```

You can be more cautious in your inner loop (e.g. use `name = row.xpath("td[@class='name']")` and so on for each bit of data), but the basic principle is the same--anchor your searches to the `tr` context.